# Hide program and reopen it from the show hidden icon

Tags: vb.net

I would like to hide my program to run in the background when I close it. When I click on the notify icon, I would the program to show up again. Thanks in advance.
Here is my code.

```
Private Sub Form_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Dim response As MsgBoxResult
    playErrorSound()
    'Message that ask user to if his action means to close the application.
    response = MsgBox("Do you want to close?", MsgBoxStyle.Question + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Confirm")
    If response = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        'Stop timer 
        Timer1.Stop()
        Me.StopWatch.Stop()
        'close program
        Me.Hide()
        Me.ShowInTaskbar = True
    ElseIf response = MsgBoxResult.No Then
        'Keep form opened
        e.Cancel = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You posted some code, can you tell us what is working and what is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the NotifyIcon control.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim WithEvents notify As New NotifyIcon

    Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        Dim myIcon As New System.Drawing.Icon("c:\stuff\myicon.ico")
        notify.Icon = myIcon
        notify.Visible = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        Dim response As MsgBoxResult
        playErrorSound()
        'Message that ask user to if his action means to close the application.
        response = MsgBox("Do you want to close?", MsgBoxStyle.Question + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Confirm")
        If response = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            'Stop timer 
            Timer1.Stop()
            Me.StopWatch.Stop()
            'close program
            Me.Hide()
            Me.ShowInTaskbar = False
            notify.Visible = True
        End If 
        e.Cancel = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub notify_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles notify.DoubleClick
        Me.Show()
        Me.ShowInTaskbar = True
        notify.Visible = False
    End Sub
End Class
```